# Lose some characters when extracting table from docx using python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

When I extract table from docx using python-docx, the result loses some characters.
This is my code:

```
file = "test.docx"
document = Document(os.path.join(path,docxf))
table = document.tables[0]
    
keys = ('item','dot')
for row in table.rows:
    text = (cell.text for cell in row.cells)   
    row_data = dict(zip(keys, text))    
    print(row_data)
```

Expected result should be {'item':'H01C/10','doc':'.'},{item':'H01L22/10','doc':'...'}
But the actual result is {'item':'H/10','doc':'.'}, losing "01C";{item':'H22/10','doc':'...'},losing "01L"

But this error would not happen if the file's format is original docx, instead of docx file which is tranformed from doc.

Why would this happen? And is there any way to solve the problem?

Comment: Maybe the information is lost in the translation from doc to docx, can you see the content stilll being correct in the translated document? You could also try to print the raw content of the table (xml) and see what elements are actually in the cells (probably by printing `row._row` or something similar).